__dirname not found in yargs module when using puppeteer
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'qwerty';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Example usage of cheerio
    const html = '<div><h1>Hello, World!</h1></div>';
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    
    const h1Text = $('h1').text();
    console.log(h1Text); // Output: Hello, World!

    this.runPuppeteer();
  }

  async runPuppeteer() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  }

Code above show a very simple initial launch of puppeteer I am trying to get into. While trying to run this simple code, I get errors:
11:15:52 AM [vite] Internal server error: __dirname is not defined
      at node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs (/Users/user1/qwerty/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs:1:61388)
      at __require2 (/Users/user1/qwerty/.angular/vite-root/qwerty/chunk-JXCON3Y3.mjs:55:50)
      at eval (/Users/user1/qwerty/node_modules/yargs/yargs.mjs:3:17)
      at async instantiateModule (file:///Users/user1/qwerty/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54758:9)
11:15:52 AM [vite] warning:
/Users/user1/qwerty/.angular/cache/17.3.2/vite/deps/puppeteer.js
51171|          try {
51172|            const { href } = (0, url_1.pathToFileURL)(filepath);
51173|            return (yield import(href)).default;
   |                                 ^^^^
51174|          } catch (error) {
51175|            try {
The above dynamic import cannot be analyzed by Vite.
See https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations for supported dynamic import formats. If this is intended to be left as-is, you can use the /* @vite-ignore */ comment inside the import() call to suppress this warning.

  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: /Users/user1/qwerty/.angular/cache/17.3.2/vite/deps/puppeteer.js?v=182ad1e6

The main problem appears to be with __dirname not being present in the yargs module, or that is what I believe. I searched online, and tried many solutions related to fidgeting with the node module, assigning import.meta.url to the __dirname property but eveything just lead to another issue.
I do not have to best experience with these types of issues for the node modules so help is appreciated.
System: macOS
Node: v20.12.0

seems like that needs to run server-side...  does it actually build?

It does build. From what I can tell - I don't believe it needs to run on server side. I though I figured out a way and added some code to index.cjs under the yargs/build folder. That seemed to fix the issue but then when using puppeteer, non of the wait functions for me. Similar to me installing and trying to use selenium-webbrowser to try that instead, it is once again giving me the __dirname error, just for a different file

usually you'd be launching an executable.  The browser sandbox would prevent that from happening.  (Else any web site could run/access any executable on your machine...)  Even though this is javascript, it needs to be run by node to launch a browser executable.
